# Deleted posts aren't excluded from daily reputation/upvotes cap

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

I would like to understand this behavior, because can't find any good explanation

This page https://stackoverflow.com/reputation shows +230 reputation and daily limit is reached (20 upvotes and two accepts). But I've deleted two my old posts with one upvote for each and reputation tab in profile shows +210 change

[image]

Why deleted posts aren't excluded? 
I see, that reputation link shows that `rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 1 days`, but will the reputation and voting be corrected later or it's an expected behavior?

I've 20 upvotes per day limit, but I've removed two of them, it should be 18. Are they excluded from a day of actual posting/upvoting?

I have an answer with 6 upvotes, and +30 reputation, because of 200 reputation limit, deleted answers with upvotes still included in a daily limit and disappear from the stats

```
 2  60184255 (10)
 2  60184255 (10)
 2  60184255 (10)
 2  60184255 (10)
 2  60184255 (10)
 2  60184255 (10)
 2  60184255 (10)
 2  60184255 (10)
 2  60186879 (10)
 1  60184255 (15)
 2  60184255 (10)
 2  60186879 (10)
 2  60186879 (10)
 2  60186879 (10)
 2  60186879 (10)
 1  60186879 (15)
 2  60186879 (10)
 2  60186879 (10)
 2  60186879 (10)
 2  60189974 (10)
 2  60189974 (10)
 2  60189974 [10]
 2  60189974 [0]
 2  60189974 [0]
 2  60189974 [0]
-- 2020-02-12 rep +230  = 8105      

** rep today: 230
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deleted posts *are* excluded from the daily reputation cap. The number at the top of the day is *not* your daily reputation cap. It is just the net change of your reputation for the day.

You've gained the maximum allowed 200 reputation from positive events for the day and you are not eligible to gain further reputation.

The removal events are simply notices that something occurred that day that caused you to lose reputation. But the actual reputation loss is calculated for the day where those events originally occurred. So if the vote on that removed post occurred on January 1, you would have lost 10 reputation from January 1, not today. If by chance you hit the reputation cap on January 1 and had additional upvotes that were capped, those would be recalculated to give you the reputation you'd be missing from the reputation cap on that original day.

It's not possible to know from the reputation history what day the votes are actually from, so you can't possibly know where to look back in your history to figure out which vote was retracted. But a removal is not a new vote on this day costing you 10 reputation. It is removing the reputation you gained from a past vote, and just notifying you today.

Comment: Thank you for the good explanation, I've got the point now. It sounds reasonable