# Why are the upvotes of deleted user is subtracted from reputation in a single day?

Tags: bug, reputation, deleted-users, daily-reputation-limit

I was just going through Jon Skeet's profile and I noticed a bug (to me, a solid one) in the StackOverflow reputation system. Then, going through Gordon Linoff's reputations, I realized something even crazier.

[image]

As you see in the image, Gordon lost 420 reputations on Oct 14 which doesn't make sense at all. Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff?tab=reputation&sort=post&page=2) his reputation page.

We know that each user can get at most 200 points per day from the upvotes. Beyond that is ignored. However, first, up to 20 upvotes are counted, then if an upvote is reverted, or a user is removed from the system, their upvotes are removed from each user's daily reputation.

So, [supposedly](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/393902/712452), if a user is removed from the system, their upvotes are subtracted from each user for the day they upvoted. However, one user who upvoted for Gordon Linoff  86 times is removed and Gordon lost 860 points for the day, not the days the user upvoted.

So my questions are:

1. Is my understanding correct?
2. If I get 21 upvotes today, and one of the users who upvoted is removed from the system, should I still not get 200 points for the day?
3. If not, why?

I know this complicates things but this is StackOverflow.

Comment: @41686d6564 The user was deleted, but probably upvoted posts on other days. Those days reputation was capped at 200. If Gorden hadn't gotten reputation from them, it wouldn't have been removed, but since it was removed, Gorden would have effectively been capped at 190 reputation points on those days (assuming each vote came of different days).

Comment: Can't see how you explain -860 points. Did the deleted user vote all of them at the same day?

Comment: @Scratte, so you say that 86 of deleted users vote came at the days when Gordon got less than 21 votes. Then why are those votes not removed from the individual days? But Oct 14?

Comment: Reputation is always removed on the day the user is deleted. But the interesting bit here is why is there a reduction at all? Lets go with your example. You get 21 upvotes, but you're capped at 200 points on monday. On tuesday a user is removed. If the user only voted once on your post on monday, you should not lose any repuation on tuesday, since only one vote is removed, leaving 20 votes in total for monday :) Your Question is very good :) In Gordon's example it's impossible for us to tell when the upvotes came in though.

Comment: @Scratte, thanks. I think we need to check other top people too for Oct 14, how they were affected. Sadly, I don't think I will ever have this situation :)

Comment: I don't think you need to check. I think perhaps your general Question here can be answered by a Stack developer or someone who knows the system very well :)

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the problem and I may be completely off... Is it assuming Gordon did reach the cap every day in its 8 years of activity here? Theoretically that deleted user had these full 8 years to span their votes, 86 votes in 8 years doesn't seem *that* much if the user was lurking in the same area as Gordon (which currently has 74K+ answers). It sounds plausible that this deleted user had more votes that are not shown in this daily summary because they were *replaced* by "over-the-cap" votes, but once again, 86 of these not being replaced also sounds possible, no?

Comment: @Kaiido, both yes and no. The issue is the deleted person's 86 upvotes should be in the days when he has less than 21 upvotes. We know that he has very few days that he has less than 20 votes (in 8 years he can collect 600k from upvotes). Unless s/he upboted everyday, I believe it is very very unlikely that this is possible. I agree there is a very very small chance though.

Comment: Now it is not it had changed